# what does safe reference means in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I am using javascript library underscore.js in that I found something called **creating safe reference by authors of underscore.js**. Can anybody explain in detail what does it mean?

Comment: "I found something" — Where? In what context? Do you have a link?

Comment: Actually I mean that the library itself tells it here http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-10